# C++ non-member functions for nested template classes

Tags: c++, templates, nested-class

I have been writing several class templates that contain nested iterator classes, for which an equality comparison is required. As I believe is fairly typical, the comparison is performed with a non-member (and non-friend) `operator==` function. In doing so, my compiler (I'm using Mingw32 GCC 4.4 with flags `-O3 -g -Wall`) fails to find the function and I have run out of possible reasons.

In the rather large block of code below there are three classes: a Base class, a Composed class that holds a Base object, and a Nested class identical to the Composed class except that it is nested within an Outer class. Non-member `operator==` functions are supplied for each. These classes are in templated and untemplated forms (in their own respective namespaces), with the latter equivalent to the former specialised for unsigned integers.

In `main`, two identical objects for each class are compared. For the untemplated case there is no problem, but for the templated case the compiler fails to find `operator==`. What's going on?

```
#include <iostream>

namespace templated {

template<typename T>
class Base {
  T t_;
public:
  explicit Base(const T& t) : t_(t) {}

  bool
  equal(const Base& x) const {
    return x.t_==t_;
  }
};

template<typename T>
bool
operator==(const Base<T> &x, const Base<T> &y) {
  return x.equal(y);
}

template<typename T>
class Composed {
  typedef Base<T> Base_;
  Base_ base_;
public:
  explicit Composed(const T& t) : base_(t) {}
  bool equal(const Composed& x) const {return x.base_==base_;}
};

template<typename T>
bool
operator==(const Composed<T> &x, const Composed<T> &y) {
  return x.equal(y);
}

template<typename T>
class Outer {
public:
  class Nested {
    typedef Base<T> Base_;
    Base_ base_;
  public:
    explicit Nested(const T& t) : base_(t) {}
    bool equal(const Nested& x) const {return x.base_==base_;}
  };
};

template<typename T>
bool
operator==(const typename Outer<T>::Nested &x,
    const typename Outer<T>::Nested &y) {
  return x.equal(y);
}

} // namespace templated

namespace untemplated {

class Base {
  unsigned int t_;
public:
  explicit Base(const unsigned int& t) : t_(t) {}

  bool
  equal(const Base& x) const {
    return x.t_==t_;
  }
};

bool
operator==(const Base &x, const Base &y) {
  return x.equal(y);
}

class Composed {
  typedef Base Base_;
  Base_ base_;
public:
  explicit Composed(const unsigned int& t) : base_(t) {}
  bool equal(const Composed& x) const {return x.base_==base_;}
};

bool
operator==(const Composed &x, const Composed &y) {
  return x.equal(y);
}

class Outer {
public:
  class Nested {
    typedef Base Base_;
    Base_ base_;
  public:
    explicit Nested(const unsigned int& t) : base_(t) {}
    bool equal(const Nested& x) const {return x.base_==base_;}
  };
};

bool
operator==(const Outer::Nested &x,
    const Outer::Nested &y) {
  return x.equal(y);
}

} // namespace untemplated

int main() {
  using std::cout;
  unsigned int testVal=3;
  { // No templates first
    typedef untemplated::Base Base_t;
    Base_t a(testVal);
    Base_t b(testVal);

    cout << "a=b=" << testVal << "\n";
    cout << "a==b ? " << (a==b ? "TRUE" : "FALSE") << "\n";

    typedef untemplated::Composed Composed_t;
    Composed_t c(testVal);
    Composed_t d(testVal);

    cout << "c=d=" << testVal << "\n";
    cout << "c==d ? " << (c==d ? "TRUE" : "FALSE") << "\n";

    typedef untemplated::Outer::Nested Nested_t;
    Nested_t e(testVal);
    Nested_t f(testVal);

    cout << "e=f=" << testVal << "\n";
    cout << "e==f ? " << (e==f ? "TRUE" : "FALSE") << "\n";
  }
  { // Now with templates
    typedef templated::Base<unsigned int> Base_t;
    Base_t a(testVal);
    Base_t b(testVal);

    cout << "a=b=" << testVal << "\n";
    cout << "a==b ? " << (a==b ? "TRUE" : "FALSE") << "\n";

    typedef templated::Composed<unsigned int> Composed_t;
    Composed_t c(testVal);
    Composed_t d(testVal);

    cout << "c=d=" << testVal << "\n";
    cout << "d==c ? " << (c==d ? "TRUE" : "FALSE") << "\n";

    typedef templated::Outer<unsigned int>::Nested Nested_t;
    Nested_t e(testVal);
    Nested_t f(testVal);

    cout << "e=f=" << testVal << "\n";
    cout << "e==f ? " << (e==f ? "TRUE" : "FALSE") << "\n";
    // Above line causes compiler error:
    // error: no match for 'operator==' in 'e == f'
  }

  cout << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This question seems appears to be about template name lookup in C++. I tried to add a name-lookup tag as this appears to be a reasonably common sub-topic, but being a newbie I lack the reputation. Would anyone more reputable like to add such a tag instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is fairly common with nested class with templates.

```
template <class T>
struct Outer { struct Inner {}; };

template <class T>
void increment(typename Outer<T>::Inner&) {}
```

The `increment` function cannot be found. I think the look up is too difficult for the compiler to solve.

You can alleviate the problem though,

```
namespace detail
{
  template <class T> struct InnerImpl {};

  template <class T> void increment(InnerImpl& ) {}
}

template <class T>
struct Outer
{
  typedef detail::InnerImpl<T> Inner;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  Outer<int>::Inner inner;
  increment(inner);         // works
}
```

Funny, isn't it ?

As a rule of thumb, `typename` in the arguments (not for the result type) of a free method is a red herring and seems to prevent automatic argument deduction.

Comment: Thanks Matthieu - I'm going with your answer, which was clear and well written. I was hoping that there was a strict rule or guidance from the Standard that might be more deterministic, but it looks like your rule of thumb is as good as it gets. That's a bit unsatisfactory, but of the language, not of your answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not standardista, meaning I can't usually cite the standard every time I need it :) Some members here like AndreyT could probably find the exact quote if it exists, but there's no real way to directly attract their attention short of posting a comment on one of their answer to another question... which is quite impolite. I wish for private messenging ;)

Answer (score 1):

After accepting an answer, I thought about how best to fix my code with the minimum effort. Armed with a clearer idea of the problem I took new inspiration from the [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.16) and merged the non-member `operator==` into the class definition as a friend function. This isn't as much of a hack as it sounds, since the reason for supplying an `equal()` member function was to avoid the need of a friend, but for templates a friend function has the benefit of allowing the function definition to be held within the class body, thus avoiding the lookup issues.

```
template<typename T>
class Outer {
public:
  class Nested {
    typedef Base<T> Base_;
    Base_ base_;
    friend bool operator==(Nested const &x, Nested const &y) {
      return x.base_==y.base_;
    }
  public:
    explicit Nested(const T& t) : base_(t) {}
  };
};
```

Answer (score -1):

If you haven't overloaded operator&, then just compare memory addresses. There's no need to do this.

Comment: If comparing for equality could be as trivial as comparing memory addresses, I think we would have figured it out much sooner.

Comment: I'm looking for insight into the problem, rather than a quick work-around. Also, in the case of iterators the most important comparison is with a sequence's end(), for which a memory address comparison is frequently unsuitable.