# Implementing non-member generic function for specific nested class of a class template

Tags: c++, templates, inner-classes, argument-dependent-lookup, name-lookup

I have the following class:

```
template<int P>
struct A {
    struct B {
        auto abs() const { return 1; }
    };
};
```

Specifically `A` is supposed to be the finite field of integers modulo P, and `B` is the class representing elements from this finite field. Then I have a generic implementation of the extended GCD algorithm which is supposed to use the `abs` function. The problem I want the extended GCD algorithm implementation to work on basic types (int, long, etc), as well as `A<P>::B`. So I need to implement a non-member `abs` that will call `A<P>::B::abs`. I tried a three techniques, two of them don't work and one that works but is not suitable.

Technique 1 (doesn't work): use argument-dependent lookup (ADL). Define the following **inside** the body of `A` but outside the body of `B`:

```
auto abs(B const &e) { return e.abs(); }
```

It won't work since ADL looks only inside namespaces not class scopes. **UPDATE** : ADL doesn't work here because `abs` is an instance method. However as per T.C.'s answer, if you make it a friend function it works correctly and ADL finds it!

Technique 2 (doesn't work): use constrained function template in global or namespace scope:

```
template<int P>
auto abs(typename A<P>::B const &e) { return e.abs(); }
```

This will also not work because `P` is in a non-deduced context.

Technique 3 (works, but not satisfactory): use unconstrained function template in global or namespace scope:

```
template<typename T>
auto abs(T const &e) { return e.abs(); }
```

This works. However, it is unconstrained. I would like to restrict instantiations of this function template only to `A<P>` (for `P` unknown beforehand), and other class templates (for polynomial rings and field extensions). The problem is I am not sure how to use SFINAE if `P` is in a non-deduced context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template<int P>
struct A {
    struct B {
        auto abs() const { return 1; }
    };
    friend auto abs(B const &e) { return e.abs(); }
//  ^^^^^^
};
```

Then let ADL work its magic.

(Defining it inside `B` is also fine. The choice's up to you.)

Comment: Is there a way to keep the declaration where it is, but provide the implementation outside the class, in another source file?

Comment: @M.Alaggan No. These instantiate into a family of non-template functions, and there's no way to spell that outside the class template definition.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
namespace impl {
    template <int P>
    struct B {
        auto abs() const { return 1; }
    };

    template <int P>
    auto abs(B<P>& b) {
        return b.abs();
    }
}

template <int P>
struct A {
    using B = impl::B<P>;
    friend B;
};

int main() {
    A<3>::B inner;
    abs(inner);
}
```

This solution uses ADL because `abs` now in the same namespace as `B`. Moreover, we avoided having `P` in a non-deduced context (`P` is not to the left of some `::` symbol) by passing the template parameter again to `B`. Unfortunately, now `B` is not a member of `A`, so if you want to give it access to `A`'s member you are going to have to make it a friend. This previous solution is due to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2882203/397405). We improve upon it next.

Alternatively, if you really want `B` to be a member of `A`, then all you need is a public facade to ensure the correct redirection:

```
namespace impl {
    template <typename T>
    struct facade : public T {};

    template <typename T>
    auto abs(facade<T>& b) { return b.abs();    }
}

template <int P>
struct A {
    struct B_ {
        auto abs() const { return 1; }
    };

    using B = impl::facade<B_ >;
};

int main() {
    A<3>::B inner;
    abs(inner);
}
```

The advantage here is that this public facade is reusable for several classes, and that it doesn't have to be a friend.